# Vim Ctrlp Plugin: ctrlp_root_markers ignores the values I set?

Tags: vim, ctrlp

My root project directory has the following:

```
root/
    .git
    Assets
    Library
    obj
    Temp
    etc.
```

Ctrlp by default looks in this root directory. I want to set the directory it starts looking in to "Assets". I looked at the docs and read in a few links that I should use `ctrlp_root_markers`, so in my `vimrc`:

```
let g:ctrlp_root_markers = ['Assets']
```

But then calling Ctrlp in vim while I'm in any source file under Assets, it always starts its indexing/search from the `root` directory. It just ignores the values I set in the root markers list. (I also tried messing with `ctrlp_working_path_mode`)

I ended up using this function (which I found lurking SO):

```
function! FindProjectRoot(lookFor)
    let pathMaker='%:p'
    while(len(expand(pathMaker))>len(expand(pathMaker.':h')))
        let pathMaker=pathMaker.':h'
        let fileToCheck=expand(pathMaker).'/'.a:lookFor
        if filereadable(fileToCheck)||isdirectory(fileToCheck)
            return expand(pathMaker).'/'.a:lookFor
        endif
    endwhile
    return 0
endfunction
```

And then remapping C-p:

```
nnoremap <C-p> :CtrlP `=FindProjectRoot("Assets")`<CR>
```

Works fine. But if a feature should be included in the core plugin I feel it's redundant to have to work-around it.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong in setting my root markers?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the expected behavior. According to the [docs](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/blob/master/doc/ctrlp.txt#L198):

```
'g:ctrlp_root_markers'
Use this to set your own root markers in addition to the default ones (.git,
.hg, .svn, .bzr, and _darcs). Your markers will take precedence:
let g:ctrlp_root_markers = ['']
```

Note that on a git project the .git folder is *inside* the project root, as shown by your example. By including `Assets` as a root marker you changed nothing.

If you intend to change your project root to `Assets` then you should include a file/folder that lies inside that folder.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I misunderstood. I thought Ctrlp takes the directory of the currently edited file, and starts navigating up till it reaches one of the defined roots, so it should reach 'Assets' and stop.